# image classifer with multiple categories

Tags: python, machine-learning

hiya i followed a guide on how to make an image classifier from here https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html and this categorizes it into only 2 categories these code gives me the F1 score and confusion matrix is there a way to make a multiple category image classifier using these codes my data sets right now are types of mushroom

```
import numpy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Mushrooms\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Mushrooms\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 7025
nb_validation_samples = 6262
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)

print(cm)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly defined a binary classification in your code. To turn it to a multi-class task, let's say to **N** class, you need to change your last layer from `1 Dense` to `N Dense`, and for the activation, you should change it from `sigmoid` to `softmax`. 
Last but not least, you should change your loss function from *binary_crossentropy* to *categorical_crossentropy* if your classes are already hot-encoded. Otherwise, you might want to go with *sparse_categorical_crossentropy*

That part of your code should seems something like this after applying the changes:

```
model.add(Dense(N))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Where N is the number of different classes you have.

Edit: you also need to go from "binary" to "categorical" for class_mode in your generators. You should also check how to generate the labels (one-hot-encoded)